# How to read output of source code in another program with C++

Tags: c++, output, stdout

I think this is really hard to explain what I want. But, let me try.
(I am trying to build a program **for scoring** student's programming homework)

There are a lot of simple source codes in C++. (Please think **there are more than 100 code files**)

```
// C:\homework1\studentA.cpp
int main()
{
    cout << "The answer is 456" << endl;
}
```

And This is question. As you can see, there are tons of code files and I cannot compile it and check it whether right or wrong one by one. So, I need to make scoring program for convenience.

How can I **read the standard output** (The answer is 456) **in another program**? Is there any function for 'compiling source code' and 'save standard output' ?

Comment: There's no function for compiling source code (unless you are willing to call `system()` or similar to invoke the compiler via a command-line invocation -- and of course that will only work if the appropriate compiler is already installed on the machine your program is running on).  For reading the stdout output of a compiled program, have a look at `popen()`.

Comment: C++ is probably not the best language of choice for this use case- The language of the assignment program is irrelevant to the choice of the language for the evaluator.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thanks to the comment I will check popen(). But, as you said, if it can't compile source code, no need to use :(

Comment: @eerorika The reason why I tried to use C++ is, students will submit homework in C++. So, I thought I don't have to use another external libraries lol. If you have recommandation, please let me know :) I can use java, python, golang or learning another stuffs.

Comment: Just for curiosity: Are you the person teaching and giving homework to those students or is it someone else?

Comment: I am also a student, and I applied to the assistant of lecture for tuition fee. But I just knew that I have to check students homework.

Comment: This question is OS dependant as much as language-irrelevant. On Linux, bash would be a solution, another would be to look into Python, Perl or any scripting language which can *easily* manipulate other applications (e.g., those written in C++ that need to be compiled and executed). Since it seems like you are running windows, the `g++` and `bash` answer below might not be so relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a bash script for this instead of C++. Something along the lines of:

```sh
g++ $filename
./a.out > student_answer.txt
diff -q student_answer.txt expected_answer.txt
```

Then, `$?` would tell you whether the answer was correct.

Comment: Unless all students can be fully trusted, for security reasons, it may be appropriate to run `a.out` as a user with very limited priviledges. Otherwise, a student's program would theoretically be able to delete all files on the user's account.

Comment: Well, in my case, I have to find out in Windows version (Batch) Thanks to guide me :)

Comment: With Windows 10 you could use bash and Linux stuff with the "Windows Subsystem for Linux", provided by Microsoft: https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/

Comment: Or run Linux in a vm, which would also be good for limiting malicious programs.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I read the standard output (The answer is 456) in another program?

You cannot do that without help from your [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system). Because you don't have (in general, according to the [C++17 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf)) some "other program" running (read about [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing))). When you have one, please thank your OS. Read some [textbook about operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).

However, on Linux, you could just use [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) (or [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) so [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html)) and on operating systems for which [Qt](https://qt.io/) has been ported (that includes Windows, but read about the [WinAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API)), you could use [QProcess](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html).

If you are paranoid, consider using [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) and/or [chroot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) techniques (perhaps with [LXC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC)) on Linux to increase the security of your tool.

Look also inside the [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) framework library.